# Pass username and password with angular 5 http request to django rest api

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, angular5

am integrating django rest api with angular 5. Django rest framework implements it's basic auth as

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    )
}
```

Am able to hit api with postman by providing django superuser (username and password) in Headers menu but when i hit api from angular it retruning 401. I have tried multiple solutions but not getting perfect solution

here is what i am trying

```
httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type':  'application/json',
        'Username': <username>,
        'Password': <password>
      })
  };

return this.http.get(url, this.httpOptions)
      .toPromise()
      .then(res=>{
        return res;
      });
```

Also tried headers as

```
httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type':  'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa('<username>:<password>')
      })
  };
```

Comment: maybe this is something to do with cors. did you try to include [django-cors-header](https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers)

Comment: @RoelDelosReyes i have installed cors extension and enabled it

Comment: but why are you including credential data through header option? just pass it as a body.

Comment: @RoelDelosReyes am sending get request. How can i send body in get request?

Comment: in that case use a query url format `api/auth/login?username=your_username&password=your_password` and access this data via `self.request.query_params.get('username')` and so on in your back end.

Comment: @RoelDelosReyes tried it but did not work. Actually am using 'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication' for authentication

Comment: post all necessary code including your view

Comment: another suggestion is to add permission in your view using `permission_classes = (AllowAny, )` only for unprotected or public resource.